# Purpose of SoapHeader namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, soap-client

I'm making a request with php SoapClient like this:

```
$auth = new stdClass();
$auth->loginId = 'test';
$auth->password = '12345';

$client = new SoapClient("example.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$header = new SoapHeader('http://example.com','Authentication',$auth,false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

My question is, what's the purpose of the `namespace` property of the SoapHeader class?  My request & authentication succeeds regardless of what I put there.

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169106&seqNum=2  forget the j2ee but there are good points for the reasons of namespaces.